# Trying to assign a value in a variable and used it in proc in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am trying to assign a value in a variable "slno" use it to insert value in table "Par_conn" . but it is giving error while executing the Procedure with parameter.Any help would be appreciated.
Table

```
create table PAR_CONN

    (
      CUSTOMER_ID   NUMBER(10) not null,
      CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR2(50) not null,
      CITY          VARCHAR2(50)
    )
```

Store Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_insert(CUSTOMER_NAME IN VARCHAR2,CITY IN VARCHAR2)
IS     
   Declare  slno number;
BEGIN 
    select count(*) into slno from Par_conn;    
    insert into Par_conn values(slno,CUSTOMER_NAME,CITY);
    commit;
 END;
```

Executing SP:

```
Begin
   sp_insert('ramesh','dispur');
  end;
```

Comment: So what you  more informative added after your edit. I guess the issue i already showed you below. Is that not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. See below comments `inline`. Not sure what you wanted to achieve but at the first place you need to make all syntatic corrections before implementing any logic.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_insert (CUSTOMER_NAME   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       CITY            IN VARCHAR2)
IS
   ---Declare  slno number; --<this is wrong way of declaration
   slno   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO slno FROM Par_conn;

   INSERT INTO Par_conn
        VALUES (slno, CUSTOMER_NAME, CITY);

   COMMIT;
END;
```

Refer here how to create a procedure .
 [Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_procedure.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Please do not reinvent wheel.

You probably aimed for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_insert(CUSTOMER_NAME IN VARCHAR2,CITY IN VARCHAR2)
IS     
    slno number;
BEGIN 
    select max(id_col_name)+1 into slno from Par_conn;    
    insert into Par_conn values(slno,CUSTOMER_NAME,CITY);
    commit;
 END;
```

to set `id` value. I would strongly recommend to use [`SEQUENCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm#SQLRF01314) or [`IDENTITY`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1).
Also you should always specify column list:

```
insert into Par_conn(col1_name, col2_name, col3_name)
values(slno,CUSTOMER_NAME,CITY);
```

Comment: using Sequence or authority permission is restricted.I tried your code but while executing store procdure Begin
   sp_insert('ramesh','dispur');
  end; it is giving error DBPRODNEW.SP_INSERT is invalid.,Statement ignored.

Comment: I tried above modified code but it is giving following error "Encountered the symbol "SP_INSERT" when expecting one of the following :=.(@ %; The symbol  ":=" was substituted for  "SP_INSERT " to continue.      execution part  Begin
   exec sp_insert('ramesh','dispur');
  end;

Comment: At very first place the syntax is wrong. Rest will work after the intial correction is made